# Jest transformers aren't working with Typescript + Webpack + PEGJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, jestjs, ts-jest

I have an NPM project:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/pegjs": "0.10.3",
    "@types/jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "9.3.1",
    "raw-loader": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.8.3",
    "webpack": "5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.10.0",
    "jest": "29.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pegjs": "0.10.0"
  }
}
```

As you can see this project:

- Has source files written in TypeScript.
- Uses Webpack for bundling.
- Uses [PegJS](https://pegjs.org/).
- Uses Jest for testing.

The structure:

```
myproj
|-src/
  |-grammar.pegjs
  |-index.ts
  |-index.test.ts
|-package.json
|-jest.config.js
|-transformer.js
```

#### Running tests

Jest will transpile `.ts` files into Javascript. As explained in the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack), we need to handle cases where we are importing static assets using Webpack. In this case, `index.ts` has this:

```
import pegjsgrammar from grammar
```

Which needs handling. I am creating a transformer just for that `transformer.js`:

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
    process(sourceText, sourcePath, options) {
        const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(sourcePath, { encoding: "utf8" }).toString();
        const json = JSON.stringify(fileContents).replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028').replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029');

        return {
            code: `module.exports = ${json};`,
        };
    },
};
```

And inside `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest",

    transform: {
      "\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
      "\\.pegjs$": "<rootDir>/pegjs_jest_transformer.js"
    },

    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "pegjs"],
  };
```

#### Errors

When running my tests, I get errors because the value in `pegjsgrammar` inside `index.ts` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is guaranteeing the interoperability between the different modules. To achieve that, modify the `tsconfig.json` to include this option:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

And it all works fine.